# Post request not beeing sent

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello I have service for sending data to my server:

```
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response,Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Transaction } from './transaction'

@Injectable()
export class TransactionSenderService{
    constructor(private http:Http){}
    private url = 'http://localhost:3000/transaction/save/';

sendTransaction(ta: Transaction) : Observable<Boolean>{
    let bodyString = JSON.stringify(ta);
    let headers      = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); // ... Set content type to JSON
    let options       = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option
    return this.http.post(this.url,bodyString,options)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
 private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = <Boolean>res.json();
    return body || {};
}
private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    // In a real world app, you might use a remote logging infrastructure
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
        const body = error.json() || '';
        const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
        errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
        errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

}

and in my `express.js` part:

```
app.post('/transaction/save/', (req, res)=>{
  var ta = req.body.ta;
  res.send("done");
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
});
```

Problem is my request is not being sent? 
I cant see anything in the network tab of browser. I have also breakpoints in express.js so I see that nothing is received. If i sent it from `Postman` then it is working.  No exceptions/errors in console. What I am doing wrong?

@UPDATE

I was asked to put here where i am calling this send:

```
export class MainComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit, OnDestroy {
  isModalVisible: Boolean;
  transactions: Transaction[];
  selectedTa: number;

  constructor(private transactionSenderService: TransactionSenderService) {}


  ngOnInit() {

  }
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    alert("Wykrywam Zmiany");
  }
  ngOnDestroy(){
        // prevent memory leak when component destroyed
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
  myValueChange(event: any) {
    console.log(event);
  }
  clearTa(): void {
    this.transactionSenderService.sendTransaction(this.transactions[this.selectedTa])     
  }      
}
```

I removed unnecesary code. This fragment is working. I can see in step by step that I am going inside send method.
More if I change `observable` to `toPromise` than request is being sent. Why?

Comment: show where you call sendTransaction

Comment: `cant see anything in the network tab`?

Comment: @SaiUnique chrome -> developers tools -> network

Comment: I know that. Can't see anything in the network tab means, there must not be any call.

Comment: @SaiUnique thats why I am asking. If I change to Promise  then there is a call but with Observale there wasnt any.  Pls check my update to question

Comment: If the server side log is enable, check is there any new entry is printed according to this request. check the method of the request is `OPTION`. Then I am sure you have CORS problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subscribe to observable to make the request, change the place where you make the call.

```
this.transactionSenderService.sendTransaction(this.transactions[this.selectedTa]).subscribe(resp => {

});
```